# What happens to a $match term in a pipeline?

Tags: python, mongodb, match, pipeline

I'm a newbie to MongoDB and Python scripts.  I'm confused how a `$match` term is handled in a pipeline.

Let's say I manage a library, where books are tracked as JSON files in a MongoDB.  There is one JSON for each copy of a book.  The book.JSON files look like this:

```
{
    "Title": "A Tale of Two Cities",
    "subData":
        {
            "status": "Checked In"
            ...more data here...
        }
}
```

Here, `status` will be one string from a finite set of strings, perhaps just:  { "Checked In", "Checked Out", "Missing", etc. }  But also note also that there may not be a `status` field at all:

```
{
    "Title": "Great Expectations",
    "subData":
        {
            ...more data here...
        }
}
```

Okay:  I am trying to write a MongoDB pipeline within a Python script that does the following:

- For each book in the library:

  - Groups and counts the different instances of the `status` field

So my target output from my Python script would be something like this:

```
{ "A Tale of Two Cities"   'Checked In'    3 }
{ "A Tale of Two Cities"   'Checked Out'   4 }
{ "Great Expectations"     'Checked In'    5 }
{ "Great Expectations"     ''    7 }
```

Here's my code:

```
mydatabase = client.JSON_DB
mycollection = mydatabase.JSON_all_2

listOfBooks = mycollection.distinct("bookname")
for book in listOfBooks:
    match_variable = {
        "$match": { 'Title': book }
    }
    group_variable = {
        "$group":{
            '_id': '$subdata.status',
            'categories' : { '$addToSet' : '$subdata.status' },
            'count': { '$sum': 1 }
        }
    }
    project_variable = {
        "$project": {
            '_id': 0,
            'categories' : 1,
            'count' : 1
        }
    }
    pipeline = [
        match_variable,
        group_variable,
        project_variable
    ]
    results = mycollection.aggregate(pipeline)
    for result in results:
        print(str(result['Title'])+"  "+str(result['categories'])+"  "+str(result['count']))
```

As you can probably tell, I have very little idea what I'm doing.  When I run the code, I get an error because I'm trying to reference my `$match` term:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testScript.py", line 34, in main
    print(str(result['Title'])+"  "+str(result['categories'])+"  "+str(result['count']))
KeyError: 'Title'
```

So a `$match` term is not included in the pipeline?  Or am I not including it in the `group_variable` or `project_variable` ?

And on a general note, the above seems like a lot of code to do something relatively easy.  Does anyone see a better way?  Its easy to find simple examples online, but this is one step of complexity away from anything I can locate.  Thank you.

Comment: It's not how databases work. Try https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M220P/about it's just 6 hrs long, and it will answer more questions than you could ask within this timeframe.

Comment: (1) The code `results = mycollection.aggregate(pipeline)` returns a _cursor_ with aggregation query result - which can be easily accessed by this code: `list(mycollection.aggregate(pipeline))`. (2) Since you are querying one book only, within the `$group` stage you can include the `Title` field: `'Title': { $first: ''$Title' }`. (3)  Finally, include the `Title` filed in the _projection_ (i.e., in the `$project` stage, to get its value in the result.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks Alex, this is really useful feedback.  I spend a lot of time slugging through other tutorials that we're really very useful.  Hence my awful code.  Appreciate the tip!

Comment: @prasad_ Hmmmmm... thanks Prasad!  Appreciate the assist.  Your comments are really useful, and make me realize how much more I have to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *one* aggregation pipeline to `"$group"` *all* the books by `"Title"` and `"subData.status"`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Title": "$Title",
        "status": {"$ifNull": ["$subData.status", ""]}
      },
      "count": { "$count": {} }
    }
  },
  { // not really necessary, but puts output in predictable order
    "$sort": {
      "_id.Title": 1,
      "_id.status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$_id",
        {"count": "$count"}
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Example output for one of the "books":

```json
  {
    "Title": "mumblecore",
    "count": 3,
    "status": ""
  },
  {
    "Title": "mumblecore",
    "count": 3,
    "status": "Checked In"
  },
  {
    "Title": "mumblecore",
    "count": 8,
    "status": "Checked Out"
  },
  {
    "Title": "mumblecore",
    "count": 6,
    "status": "Missing"
  }
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8MIZVrjCrLg).